# IEnumerable<T> in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am trying to get the following code to compile but am getting errors in VS2008.  Anyone can tell me where I am going wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace dummy
{
    public class NaturalNumbersSequence : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                yield return i;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                yield return i;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (int i in new NaturalNumbersSequence())
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, it's a good idea to post the error messages you're getting as well.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, the first compiler error I get is that it complains that:

> Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' requires '1' type arguments

This is on line 16, this one:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
```

Fixing that by adding a using directive for the `System.Collections` namespace (tip: place the cursor just after IEnumerator, on the *r* at the end of the word, and hit Ctrl+. (ctrl + the dot-key), it should suggest you add a "using System.Collections;" directive, do that).

Then it compiles, and runs. Does that match what you expect?

Also, note that you should always post the actual error messages you're getting, this way we're not barking up the wrong tree if there's something else wrong with your code that we're not seeing at first glance.

Additionally, you can simplify this very common implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` by calling one of the methods from the other, hence I would simplify the implementation of the second methods like this:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator(); // this will return the one
                            // available through the object reference
                            // ie. "IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator"
}
```

this way you only implement the actual enumerator code once.

And finally see [Earwicker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27423/earwicker)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174713/ienumerablet-in-c/1174736#1174736) as well, it shows a better (in my opinion at least) way to write this whole code.

Comment: +1. The last part about reusing one implementation of the enumerator on the other is the icing on the cake.

Comment: why are there 2 implementations of the enumerator in the first place?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure why you're getting errors, but wouldn't this be simpler?

```
public static class NumbersSequence
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Naturals
    {
        get 
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
                yield return i;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (int i in NumbersSequence.Naturals)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Everybody knows that numbers above 1000 are unnaturally high.

Comment: For me, the distinction between "regular" and "large" numbers is at twenty thousand. I guess that is an "implementation" thing.

Comment: Twenty thousand is insanely high. Wait.... we're talking developer salaries here, right guys?

Comment: It's also interesting to see the age old dispute emerging here over whether the natural numbers start at zero or one!

Comment: If it's number theory, 1 is the only number. Everything else is the result of the successor operator.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly off-topic, but perhaps interesting to see is this approach:

```
public static class NumbersSequence
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Naturals
    {
        get 
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(true)
                yield return i++;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (int i in NumbersSequence.Naturals.Take(1000))
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

C# 3.0 afaik. Pay attention to the seemingly endless loop in the getter, and the call to Take(1000). With this method you now have an 'endless' sequence of natural numbers (endless up until the maxvalue of an int). It won't get stuck, as long as you tell it to take a specific amount.

DISCLAIMER:
Most of the code borrowed from Earwicker's answer.

Comment: So what's `i` in `Naturals.get`?

Comment: Always nice to see "infinite" loops in action.

Comment: As Pavel noticed, you're missing initialization and increment of i.

Comment: I love me some Linq, but man I would definitely forget to .Take() in this case.  I'd prefer to have Naturals be a method accepting an int parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "yield return i++"?

Comment: This isn't right - you should declare `i` inside the `get`. The way you have it now, a second evaluation of `NumbersSequence.Naturals.Take(1000)` will return the numbers 1000 through 1999. Which should be the answer to `NumbersSequence.Naturals.Skip(1000).Take(1000)`

Comment: Instead of `while(true)`, I would do `while(i < int.MaxValue)`

Answer (score 2):

Lasse has the right answer, and I know this is learning code, but in the interest of furthering your learning I want to mention two things:

1. `Enumerable.Range()`
2. Take some time to think about this implementation:

.

```
public class NaturalNumbersSequence : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i=0 i <= int.MaxValue;i++)
            yield return i;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i=0 i <= int.MaxValue;i++)
            yield return i;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (int i in new NaturalNumbersSequence().TakeWhile(i => i<=1000) )
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```